# GetIDsOfNames always fails with RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER for getting a property ID in Photoshop

Tags: c++, windows, com, photoshop, ole

I wrote the following C++ code, trying to perform some OLE automation tasks
for currently-running Photoshop:

```
    IUnknown* unk = NULL;
    IDispatch* disp = NULL;

    CLSID clsId;
    if (FAILED(CLSIDFromProgID(L"Photoshop.Application", &clsId)))
        goto err;
    puts("CLSIDFromProgID succeeded");

    if (FAILED(GetActiveObject(&clsId, NULL, &unk)))
        goto err;
    puts("GetActiveObject succeeded");

    if (FAILED(IUnknown_QueryInterface(unk, &IID_IDispatch, (void**)&disp)))
        goto err;
    puts("QueryInterface succeeded");

    DISPID dispId;
    HRESULT resultOfGettingId = IDispatch_GetIDsOfNames(disp, &IID_NULL,
        (LPOLESTR[1]){L"ActiveDocument"}, 1,
        LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispId);
    if (FAILED(resultOfGettingId))
    {
        //The code always goes here.
        //The result code is printed as 0X8001010A,
        //which is RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER.
        printf("GetIDsOfNames for <ActiveDocument> failed. Result code: %#lX.\n",
            resultOfGettingId);
        goto err;
    }
    puts("GetIDsOfNames for Selection succeeded");
```

The above C++ code always prints the following text (whenever I run it):

> GetIDsOfNames for <ActiveDocument> failed. Result code: 0X8001010A.

After searching for *RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER*, I found that the error code
seems to mean that the application is busy. But Photoshop is just opened, and
not being manipulated at all, and just contains only a single empty document.
How can it always be busy?

And why does the equivalent C# code such as

```
try
{
    activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.font = "FZCYJW--GB1-0";
}
catch(e)
{
    ...
}
```

works fine?

It doesn't make sense that Photoshop just happens to be busy everytime
when the C++ program is trying to connect.

Something problematic other than the so-called busyness must be hiden
in the details but I just have no clue.

Edit:

Issued resloved!

I've found the culprit of "busyness". If Photoshop is in the state of selecting some text, then it fails, otherwise it succeeds. So when some text is selected, Photoshop is in a state where it thinks handleing COM call-ins out of process isn't a good idea.

Comment: There is currently no official OLE Support by Windows till now from C. Kindly add C++ tag to get better response.

Comment: @RewCie Thank you for your tag. But I believe the C# code's underlying interface is also COM/OLE.

Comment: C# are C++ are different. It's possible for it to work in C# but not in C++ due to implementation issues. If anyone with idea of OLE in C++ will look your question, \he'll answer your question.

Comment: @rew That's complete bugs. OLE is COM, and [COM has 2 requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model): Creating structures of pointers and calling functions through pointers. Clearly C can do both.

Comment: I've tested your C code and it works fine for me (PS 22.1.0 64bit open with one image) in x86 and x64, dispid is 1883325539. Might want to try reboot, or reinstall PS or contact Adobe.

Comment: Two thoughts... 1) Sure GetActiveObject() isn't creating another instance? 2) I might change your argument from (LPOLESTR[1]){L"ActiveDocument"} to &L"ActiveDocument"

Comment: @RewCie - you should remove your edits. It's C, not C++ the question has nothing to do with C++ vs C.

Comment: @SimonMourier I found the issue: if Photoshop is in the state of selecting some text, then it fails, otherwise it succeeds. So when some text is selected, Photoshop is in a state where it thinks handleing COM call-ins out of process isn't a good idea.

Comment: You should answer yourself then.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the culprit of "busyness". If Photoshop is in the state of selecting some text, then it fails, otherwise it succeeds. So when some text is selected, Photoshop is in a state where it thinks handling COM call-ins out of process isn't a good idea.